# Android: SharedPreferences getStringSet() returns onlu [] or [1] after starting the application

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sharedpreferences

I am trying to use `SharedPreferences` as a storage for my '**favorite item ids**'. I am using this in my Kotlin Android app.

When I call method for storing values into `SharedPreferences`, I'd like to save `Set` of `Strings`. Values are present in the `SharedPreferences` object anytime I check them in my application. But when I close the app (close the app on background or when app crashes) and then open the app again the content of `SharedPreferences` is `[]` if I don't save anything in the `SharedPreferences` during the app run. If I save something into `SharedPreferences` close the app and open it once again it loads `Set` with exactly one element `[1]`.

It seems that anytime I store something in the `SharedPreferences` using `putStringSet()` a `Set` with only one element `[1]` is written int `SharedPreferences` after the application crashes or is closed.

I've debugged the app many times, put the debug logs everywhere, but cannot find the reason.

Could anyone help?

I am not sure whether I need some permissions in `AndroidManifest` or somewhere else?

To make a better picture of the app:

Iam using android Emulator (perhaps it requires some special settings?)

More activities are accessing the same `SharedPreferences`, basically in one activity I write into it and in the other I read from it.

This method I am using for storing values into SharedPreferences:

```
fun saveFavorite(id: Long){
    val favorites = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(preferencesKey, setOf<String>())
    favorites.add(id.toString())
    with (sharedPreferences.edit()) {
       putStringSet(preferencesKey, favorites)
       commit()
    }
}
```

And this method I am using for getting values from SharedPreferences:

```
fun getFavorites(): Set<String>{
    val favorites = sharedPreferences.getStringSet(preferencesKey, setOf<String>())
    return favorites
}
```

Comment: You cannot try to modify and save back the `Set` that `getStringSet()` returns. You have to create a new `Set` instance.

Comment: Thanks Mike! That resolved my issue. Maybe I should have read documentation before :)